# java spring mvc 404 not found error for sample Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am learning spring MVC and getting the below problem.Even I am not able to run any sample application downloaded from internet as well.
I am getting 404 Not Found "Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists."

I have tried the below

1. Adding the Maven dependencies in Deployment Assembly.
2. Changing the Tomcat server path.

   ```java
    @Controller
    public class ControllerClass{


        @RequestMapping("hello")
        public String redirect() {

            return "Hello";
        }
    }
   ```

This is my Controller class

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd ">
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.practice.controllerclasses" />
  <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
  </bean>
  <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
  <mvc:annotation-driven />
</beans>
```

is my DispatcherServletConfiguration xml file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 

<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
  <welcome-file-list>
  
  <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>Spring</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  
  <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Spring</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  
</web-app>
```

is my web.xml file

[image: is my folder hierchy]

I am using Eclipse JEE 2019-09 Jre1.8 and Spring 4.1

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How are you deploying that to Tomcat?

Comment: Im not even deploying im just doing the debug run in eclipse.I have added the Tomcat Runtime environment to eclipse